# Problem stating the points under paragrah

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

This is what I am trying to do

```
We discuss here SW coding with the help of a toy example. In this example, we assume   that 
X and Y are each of 3 bits. Moreover, X and Y differs at most in one bit. 
Following is the sequence how the SW coding works:

1.Make cosets of X's with Hamming distance 3:(000,111),(001,110),(010,101),(011,100)

2. Send index of set (requires 2 bits)

3. Send Y (requires 3 bits)

4. Decode X by using the element in the set which is closest 
to Y

5. Declare error if no element with d_H \leq 1
```

The output I see looks like this

[image: Output]

I would like the new line which is created to be aligned as marked with red line in above example.

Comment: You shouldn't perform this enumeration manually. Note how the spacing for `1.` is different from that in `2.` onward, just because you forgot to insert a space. Use a list to enumerate the content and adjust the list settings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't enumerate content manually. Instead, use a list that enumerates the content automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Hello, my name is John Doe. I study applied mathematics and I enjoy the following subjects:
  calculus, differential equations, number theory, set theory, computer science, etc.

  \item
  Hello, my name is Jane Doe. I really enjoy writing poetry, even though I don't know anything
  about rhymes.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Manipulations to the list formatting is available via the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). For example, the following key-value changes can be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}, labelsep=2em]
  \item
  Hello, my name is John Doe. I study applied mathematics and I enjoy the following subjects:
  calculus, differential equations, number theory, set theory, computer science, etc.

  \item
  Hello, my name is Jane Doe. I really enjoy writing poetry, even though I don't know anything
  about rhymes.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. It worked. Can you please also guide me how to change the spacing after numeric number. In my case, it is like                         1)  Big space {here comes my text}, I would like the space to be less and instead of 1), it should be 1. like the image you pasted